# Semantic UI React : How to set content load on pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using Semantic UI React pagination to load server data . I am beginner to ReactJS, Could someone please help me to figure out how I can set page call on individual number ( 1,2,3 ). For example when user click on `1` it retrieve limited data around `10` entries , same like when user click on `2` it load further entries `10-20` and it maintain same manner. Please help me because I am new . Thanks

**Pagination Code from Semantic UI React**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Pagination } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const PaginationExampleCompact = () => (
  <Pagination
    boundaryRange={0}
    defaultActivePage={1}
    ellipsisItem={null}
    firstItem={null}
    lastItem={null}
    siblingRange={1}
    totalPages={10}
  />
)

export default PaginationExampleCompact
```

Answer (score 1):

Semantic UI library support some components with its properties.
You can customize that supported component.
One of the most important thing is that Pagination component is only for UI interface.
You can customize default pagination component by setting property value.
You have to send request to backend with specific pagination id and backend would respond with id matched result.
On the whole, all the functionality must be implemented on backend.
In frontend, you can only implement api request and handling response.
So you should concern mostly on backend api implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to handle state of the page number and which items are being displayed.

Working Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-voice-l1dc5

```
export class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page: 2,
      itemsPerPage: 10,
    };
    this.items = createItems(100);
  }

  setPageNum = (event, { activePage }) => {
    this.setState({ page: activePage });
  };

  render() {
    const itemsPerPage = 10;
    const { page } = this.state;
    const totalPages = this.items.length / itemsPerPage;
    const items = this.items.slice(
      (page - 1) * itemsPerPage,
      (page - 1) * itemsPerPage + itemsPerPage
    );
    console.log(items);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <List divided>
          {items.map(item => (
            <List.Item key={item}>{item}</List.Item>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Pagination
          activePage={page}
          totalPages={totalPages}
          siblingRange={1}
          onPageChange={this.setPageNum}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```